# IndexError: list index out of range... Dictionary mapping

Tags: python-3.x

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Project\wordData.py", line 60, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python34\Project\wordData.py", line 58, in main
    print(totalOccurences(word, readWordFile(fileName)))
  File "C:\Python34\Project\wordData.py", line 31, in readWordFile
    yc = createYearCount(int(new[1]), int(new[2]))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm trying to test my functions. With a sample file, readWordFile should return:

```
{’airport’: [YearCount( year=2007, count=175702 ), YearCount( year=2008,
count=173294 )], ’wandered’: [YearCount( year=2005, count=83769 ),
YearCount( year=2006, count=87688 ), YearCount( year=2007, count=108634 ),
YearCount( year=2008, count=171015 )], ’request’: [YearCount( year=2005,
count=646179 ), YearCount( year=2006, count=677820 ), YearCount( year=2007,
count=697645 ), YearCount( year=2008, count=795265 )]}
```

and totalOccurences should take in word(word searching for) and words( a dictionary mapping words to lists of YearCount objects)

ex.

```
print(totalOccurences('wandered', readWordFile(fileName)))
451106
```

Full code:

```
class YearCount(rit_object):
    """
    Year count object taking the year and count as slots
    """
    __slots__ = ( 'year', 'count')
    _types = (int, int)

def createYearCount(year, count):
    return YearCount(year, count)

def readWordFile(fileName):
    #read in the entire unigram dataset
    """
    A dictionary mapping words to lists of YearCount objects.
    For every word, there is exactly one list of YearCount objects.
    Each YearCount object contains a year in which a
    word appeared and the count of the number of times the
    word appeared that year. 
    """
    dictionary = {}
    for line in fileName:
        new = line.split(', ') 
        id = new[0]
        yc = createYearCount(int(new[1]), int(new[2]))
        # add to list or create a new list
        if not id in dictionary:
            dictionary[id] = [yc]
        else:
            dictionary[id].append(yc)
    return dictionary

def totalOccurences(word, words):
    """
    Output: The total number of times that a word has appeared
    in a book in the entire dataset.
    return; count(total amount of times a word has appeared)
    param; word(the word for which to calculate the count)
           words(A dictionary mapping words to lists of YearCount objects)
    """
    if word not in words:
        return 0
    count = 0
    for item in words[word]:
        count += item.count
    return count

def main():
    fileName = input('Enter filename: ')
    readWordFile(open(fileName))
    word = input('Enter word to search for: ')
    print(totalOccurences(word, readWordFile(fileName)))

main()
```

text file:

```
airport, 2007, 175702
airport, 2008, 173294
request, 2005, 646179
request, 2006, 677820
request, 2007, 697645
request, 2008, 795265
wandered, 2005, 83769
wandered, 2006, 87688
wandered, 2007, 108634
wandered, 2008, 171015
```

ANy simpler methods to testing my program? I keep getting list index out of range error.

Comment: What are the contents of the file? Are there lines that don't have 3 elements in that line?

Comment: Ill put the text file up

Comment: Is there an empty line in the file?

Comment: No, that's the layout

Comment: My readWorldFile function works correctly, it's just my totalOccurences function that I'm having issues with

Comment: But the error happens in `readWordFile`: it's saying that `new` doesn't have enough elements as you're getting an `IndexError` on that list. So there must be something with the file or the way you're getting the file data that's giving this error. The function `totalOccurences` seems fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got 0, because you read the file once after you open it - it will move it's file pointer to the end of the file, and next time you use the readWordFile(fileName) function, it will start from the end of the file - so it won't find/read anything.

You can use a variable and reuse it later, or just delete the first usage of the function.

```
data = readWordFile(open(fileName))
word = input('Enter word to search for: ')
print(totalOccurences(word, data))
```

P.s.:
You should check the new variable's length after the split, but before using it: